# Typescript complaining existing object doesn't exist

Tags: angular, typescript

From CartComponent I am calling the removeItem() function in CartService.

CartComponent#removeItem():

```
public removeItem(itemId:string) {
    this.cartService.removeItem(itemId).subscribe(cart => {
      console.log('CartComponent#removeItem', )
      this.cartItems = cart.cartItem;
    });
  }
```

Typescript is giving the following error for cart.cartItem:

```
[ts] Property 'cartItem' does not exist on type 'void'.
any
```

I have done precisely this in another application and it works just fine.

CartService#removeItem()

```
public removeItem(itemId:string) {
   console.log('CartService#removeItem', itemId)
   return this.httpClient.delete<Cart>(`${this.cartItemUrl}${itemId}`)
   .pipe(
     tap(cart => console.log('cart@removeItem', cart)),
     // map(cart => this.cart = cart, this.setItemCount()),
     map(cart => {
       this.cart = cart;
       this.setItemCount();
     }),
     catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function is used to transform the emitted value of the `Observable`. Whatever is returned from `map` will be the emitted value.

If your case, nothing is returned from your `map` function, so the `subscribe` in `CartComponent` has no way of accessing the value.

Comment: I do have a return statement in CartService#removeItem and this worked in other codes.

Comment: No, you need another one inside the `map` function, underneath `this.setItemCount()` you probably want `return this.cart` as well. If `map` doesn't return anything your observable will emit undefined

Comment: just a side note, use map when you are trying to map the response, in example, transform it to something else. what you did inside the map has nothing to do with the response transformation, hence, do it inside the tap. so the response won't change, but you may want to do other stuff related to the response inside the service itself (like your console.log)